# Failed to load resource (JS files in PACK) in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Everything was nice, I did a minor change installing a gem to use Google Analytics and for a while all worked fine. At some point I realized all the javascript in `/packs/` was not being loaded. After hours trying to fix it I decided to make a `git reset --hard` to a previous version in which everything worked.

My surprise was that this error keep happening. It failed to load the javascript in `/pack/` (I use also StimulusJS).

I have tried all I have found:

- turning config.assets.compile to true
- checking StimulusJS initial configuration
- using diff to see for typos...

Nothing.

It seems it happens just in production.

What am I missing?

Repo: https://github.com/juansecaro/guialocal

[image]

Comment: You tried to manually do `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing changed. Is it possible a gem overwrited something in base configuration? Even though I have checked suspicious files, I can find changes.